# Right now I am writing codes in sublime text software and running them in cmd. But when I run this set of codes nothing happens. why?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to coding in python. Right now I am writing codes in sublime text software and running them in cmd. But when I run this set of codes nothing happens. why??

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: " ))
    print("The number entered by you is" + num)

    mod = num % 2

    if mod == 0:
        print("The number entered is even")

    else:
        print("The number is odd")
```

Comment: How are you running this code in `cmd`? Are you changing directory in `cmd` to the same directory where your code is saved to a file? If you saved this code in a file named `script.py`, is your command `python script.py`?

Comment: I double the @downshift 's question – there is some ambiguity in interpreting what exactly is not working here. Maybe you have a windows, and the environment variable 'python' is not set, who knows... OP, please elaborate on the problem that you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit rusty with python myself, but this should be easy. Try adding the following line in the beginning of your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Or, put your code in the function (let's say, pick_a_number()), and then you could do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pick_a_number()
```

Comment: whats the use of this?

Comment: It is basically `public static void main(String[] args) {}` in the world of python. It is more useful when one has python classes, and would like to call the methods from those classes. But should work anyway.